# UWP memory leak using webview in MVVMCross application

Tags: memory, webview, uwp, mvvmcross, unmanaged

I have a MVVMCross UWP application.
The first views are not remarkable until the user comes to a welcome page and from there goes to a dashboard.
Here lies a problem, somewhere is a memory leak and I can't find it.
The graphic shows memory usage in MB and navigations from welcome->dashboard and back.

The first section is navigating to a dashboard without an embedded webview, the second section has a webview element which loads a rather complex page with embedded video.

Some notes:

- The webview, when enabled is loaded in code behind using the SeperateThread flag and set as the content of a ContentControl
- On unloading the view I explicitly set the content of the ContentControl back to null, the temp value to null that holds the webview and manually call GC.Collect. If I do not do this the webview will continue playing the video in the background until the GC kicks in
- I use a custom presenter (adding support for popups and to implement and call IDispoable/Dispose for my viewmodels (to not wait for the GC to clear subscriptions and such)
- When analyzing memory dumps I can not see any changes in managed objects or memory

There seems to be a problem (a small leak) when not using the webview and I will look into this as well, right now I am more concerned about the second scenario

Where should I continue to ivestigate what is going on?

Thank you!

[memory over several hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZESr.png)

EDIT:
Test Application available (see comments)
Just let it run for about 30 minutes to see the problem. Memory will steadily increase slightly until the application crashes (might take a few hours).
I kinda messed up the display and % for the memory usage. just watch application memory in task manager or export a csv file with the raw data

[Same progression in sample app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shuHD.png)

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue? Without any code, it's hard to find where the problem is.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. I wanted to create one anyway to figure out wether MVVMCross or UWP itself is to blame. We worked around the issue for now by clearing the webview cache periodically, which drastically reduces unmanaged memory usage. But it still builds up over time.

Comment: Test App is now available: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=38731557679452248517
Just let it run for ~30 minutes and the problem becomes very visible. I can see the same increase in memory as in our main app. You can also export the data as a csv file to plot it in excel